# 2010 TDI Jetta Strange A/C Pressure Readings

Tags: vw, ac, jetta, pressure, cooling

I recently replaced the compressor and dryer at the suggestion of a nearby shop. I've charged the system and the high side reads a solid 100psi the low side cycles between 70 - 110. Cycle time is about 2-3 seconds. As some of you may know this car does not have a clutch it is a variable displacement compressor. 
Strange thing is that this is what it was doing before too. Anyone know anything about how to test the PAG or the pressure sensors?

Any reasonable suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
LibertysChild

Comment: Good question and welcome to the site.  You should register your user and change your name rather than signing your question.

Answer (score 1):

The values seem awfully high on the low side. The high side is the output of the compressor to the condenser coil where the refrigerant is in liquid form. The low side pressures should be about a third of the high value. The low side is the line to the evaporator coil (inside the vehicle) which is vapor form. When the system is being charged it is from the low side line. Furthermore all air conditioning units require specific quantities and type of refrigerant. 
Most car compressors are 1 ton units (12000 Btu) with .75kg of refrigerant.
Usually the cycle times are in the order of about 10-20 seconds. I recommend  that you have the pressures checked by a qualified technician. Based on the pressures you might have too much refrigerant in the system which could damage your compressor.

Comment: It also seems awfully low on the high side.